# JavaScript :Prevent download of js if file code not changed

Tags: javascript

I am doing defer loading of js file this way. so it is downloading every time and file size is huge.
so is it possible to determine the file has changed or not by js. if file has changed then it will download other wise take the file from cache.

now i am doing js file this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJs() 
{
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "/Scripts/JQueryBundle?v=vFo0kKa-_2_wGzi6Q0u-IemkcVvXrEdKz7OrQ9g-y_c1";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
        
</script>

// Check for browser support of event handling capability
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJs, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJs);
else
    window.onload = downloadJs;
```

so please advise me what more code need to plug in above code to add this behavior. i am looking for a way that my routine will detect if js file has been changed then it will download from server otherwise load js file from browser cache.

Thanks

Comment: Do you create the JS file in question?

Comment: If you have your server side set up correctly it should cache automatically, looking at the script name you could do this with a long expire, or let the server send a 304 not modified response.

Comment: see the code here i am forcing the js file download. i am not detecting file is changed at server side or not. my downloadJs() function is downloading same js file again and again. so file is not taking from browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service worker to cache files.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Also you can use web manifest/application cache.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/